# Python3: Multiprocessing closing psycopg2 connections to Postgres at AWS RDS

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-rds, python-multiprocessing, psycopg2

I'm trying to write chunk of 100000 rows to AWS RDS PostgreSQL server. 
I'm using psycopg2.8 and multiprocessing. I'm creating new connection in each process and preparing the SQL statement as well. But every time random amount of rows are getting inserted. I assume the issue is the python multiprocessing library closing wrong connections, which is mentioned here:[multiprocessing module and distinct psycopg2 connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404773/multiprocessing-module-and-distinct-psycopg2-connections)
and here:https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/829 in one of the comment.
The RDS server logs says:
LOG: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
LOG: unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction

Here is the skeleton of the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import csv
from psycopg2 import sql
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import connection

def gen_chunks(reader, chunksize= 10 ** 5):
""" 
Chunk generator. Take a CSV `reader` and yield
`chunksize` sized slices. 
"""
chunk = []
for index, line in enumerate(reader):
    if (index % chunksize == 0 and index > 0):
        yield chunk
        del chunk[:]
    chunk.append(line)
yield chunk    

def write_process(chunk, postgres_conn_uri):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(dsn=postgres_conn_uri)
    with conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute(
            '''PREPARE scrape_info_query_plan (int, bool, bool) AS 
                INSERT INTO schema_name.table_name (a, b, c)
                VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
                ON CONFLICT (a, b) DO UPDATE SET (c) = (EXCLUDED.c)
                '''
            )
            for row in chunk:
                cur.execute(
                    sql.SQL(
                    ''' EXECUTE scrape_info_query_plan ({})''').format(sql.SQL(', ').join([sql.Literal(value) for value in [1,True,True]]))  
                    )

pool = Pool()
reader = csv.DictReader('csv file path', skipinitialspace=True)
for chunk in gen_chunks(reader):
    #chunk is array of row's(100000) from csv
    pool.apply_async(write_process, [chunk, postgres_conn_uri])
```

commands to create required DB stuff:
1. CREATE DATABASE foo;
2. CREATE SCHEMA schema_name;
3. CREATE TABLE table_name (
   x serial PRIMARY KEY,
   a integer,
   b boolean,
   c boolean;

Any suggestions on this?

Note: I'm having EC2 instance with 64 vCPU and I can see 60 to 64 parallel connection on my RDS instance.

Comment: Please post a simple, runnable example which produces the problem.

Comment: @jjanes, I've added code which produces the problem, you will need one csv file(little bit big) and postgres server to run the code. Thank!

Comment: Since you aren't logging errors, it is not surprising this is hard to debug.  I get File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
NameError: global name 'sql' is not defined

Comment: I've fixed the script. One thing to add is, for this issue there is no any error logs client side, I'm getting "connection reset from client" error in postgres's server logs though.

Comment: With this script, you wouldn't know if you are getting errors on the client side.  You don't have any error logging, and you aren't harvesting errors from the subprocesses.  You need to save the result of apply_async someplace, then later call .get() on it.